# fullcalendar - "Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin"

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

So i have this error:

> Uncaught Error: Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin.

The problem is that plugins are loaded before importing the main fullcalendar. But my imports are ordered correctly.

```
import {Calendar} from '@fullcalendar/core';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import googleCalendarPlugin from '@fullcalendar/google-calendar';
```

.

```
const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin, googleCalendarPlugin],
```

I have looked online for a solution and all stated the same that the import orders are incorrect (that was also visible with the persons asking the questions code). But i am sure mine is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@fullcalendar/google-calendar` and `@fullcalendar/core` are incompatible. Make sure that the major version is identical:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-euler-ginty?file=/package.json