# fullcalendar - NextJS - Dynamic import doesn't show calendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, next.js, fullcalendar-5, react-loadable

I'm using NextJS and Fullcalendar.

I tried to use `fullcalendar` using dynamic import like in [this example](https://www.davidangulo.xyz/how-to-use-fullcalendar-in-next-js/)(for more info, this example solution comes from [here](https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/using-fullcalendar-with-next-js%7E6800b0f7-a423-4916-8a60-356c9b1b9ff4)).

It worked, But there was a problem. Almost every 1 out of 5 refreshing attempts ended in error `Please import the top-level fullcalendar lib before attempting to import a plugin` ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356915/fullcalendar-please-import-the-top-level-fullcalendar-lib-before-attempting-t), but versions are correct in my case)

After that, I found out that the modules option for next/dynamic has been deprecated. I thought it was a source of my problem (I'm not sure 100%, but at least it was deprecated and needed to be updated).

As [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) says, newer way to handle dynamic imports is like this:

```js
const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod.Hello)
)
```

But because we need multiple imports I found [this solution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13139).

For now, It seems like everything should be working, but my code has no effect.

```js
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "@fullcalendar/common/main.css"; // @fullcalendar/react imports @fullcalendar/common
import "@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css"; // @fullcalendar/timegrid imports @fullcalendar/daygrid
import "@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css"; // @fullcalendar/timegrid is a direct import
import "./Fullcalendar.module.scss";
let CalendarComponent;

const Calendar = dynamic(() =>
  import("@fullcalendar/react").then((module) => module.Calendar)
);
const dayGridPlugin = dynamic(() =>
  import("@fullcalendar/daygrid").then((module) => module.dayGridPlugin)
);

export default function FullCalendar(props) {
  const [calendarLoaded, setCalendarLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    CalendarComponent = () => (
      <Calendar
        {...props}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
      />
    );
    setCalendarLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  let showCalendar = (props) => {
    if (!calendarLoaded) return <div>Loading ...</div>;
    return <CalendarComponent {...props} />;
  };

  return <div>{showCalendar(props)}</div>;
}
```

I also find another way to use [next transpile modules](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/next).
But they say that `"there is currently no way to transpile only parts of a package, it's all or nothing"`.

In fact, I have something in `next.config.js`. Editing this file into transpile modules is another mysterious adventure, full of problems.

What should I have to do?

Answer (score 9):

I know the OP was asking for help making it work with a dynamic import, but in case anyone comes across this question trying to get FullCalendar to work with next.js in general (with or without dynamic importing) I hope this answer will help. My answer is a modification of [@juliomalves' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66951960/2430765).

(1) Like @juliomalves and the official example, I installed `next-transpile-modules`, and included the appropriate dependencies

```
// next.config.js

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  "@fullcalendar/common",
  "@fullcalendar/daygrid",
  "@fullcalendar/timegrid",
  "@fullcalendar/interaction",
  "@fullcalendar/react",
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  // any other next.js settings here
});
```

(2) Instead of modifying babel, I left it as is. Did not add a babel.config.js, or the babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore plugin.

(3) I added the appropriate CSS in the same way as the official example.

```
// _app.tsx

import '@fullcalendar/common/main.css'
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css'
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css'
```

(4) I imported the FullCalendar dependencies in my custom component.

```
// components/FullCalendar.tsx

import Calendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import styles from './Fullcalendar.module.scss';

export default function FullCalendar(props) {
    return (
       <Calendar {...props} plugins={[dayGridPlugin]} initialView="dayGridMonth" />
    );
}
```

(5) And then instead of importing dynamically, I imported regularly into the page where I needed the calendar.

Comment: It seems that the solution provided doesn't work for Typescript and Next.js, but this solution worked for me. Thanks so much!!! They really need to update the site to have a Next and TS example. If feel like it's getting pretty common and I don't know of a good reason not to use TS.

Comment: This worked for me in NextJS 11.1.2. Watch out for the component name. I kept trying 'FullCalendar' when the component to use is called 'Calendar'.

Comment: I use Fullcalendar v6 and Next js 12. If I run my app in dev mode, this solution works. But it doesnt work in build mode. Does anyone have a solution for this versions?

Answer (score 2):

Making FullCalendar work properly with Next.js requires some initial setup and a few changes to your initial code.

First, let's install `next-transpile-modules` to process `fullcalendar`'s ES modules. Make sure to include all `@fullcalendar` dependencies you use.

```js
// next.config.js

const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  '@fullcalendar/common',
  '@fullcalendar/react',
  '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  // any other next.js settings here
});
```

Next, add a custom Babel configuration to ignore CSS imports used in `fullcalendar` - `babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore` plugin will need to be installed. This prevents the [`Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules` error](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5393) from Next.js.

```js
// babel.config.js

module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-react'
    ],
    overrides: [
        {
            include: ['./node_modules'],
            plugins: [
                [
                    'babel-plugin-transform-require-ignore',
                    {
                        extensions: ['.css']
                    }
                 ]
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

You'll have to include `fullcalendar`'s global CSS in `_app.js` to compensate for this. Global CSS can only be imported from this file in Next.js.

```js
// _app.js

import '@fullcalendar/common/main.css'
import '@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css'
import '@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css'
```

Finally, you can simplify and refactor your `FullCalendar` component. Here you don't have to dynamically import its `fullcalendar` dependencies, we'll dynamically import the component itself when using it.

```js
// components/FullCalendar.jsx

import Calendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import styles from './Fullcalendar.module.scss';

export default function FullCalendar(props) {
    return (
       <Calendar {...props} plugins={[dayGridPlugin]} initialView="dayGridMonth" />
    );
}
```

Then, dynamically import your custom component wherever it's used.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const FullCalendar = dynamic(() => import('../components/FullCalendar'), {
    ssr: false
});

const SomePage = () => {
    return <FullCalendar />;
}

export default SomePage;
```

For reference, this is based on the [official example](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/next) from `fullcalendar`, with some adaptations to make it work with `next-transiple-modules` v6.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Other implementation that's using `next-transpile-modules` may not work anymore in NextJS 13 (or NextJS 12 as well refer to @dikembe-mutombo).

According to [FullCalendar example](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/tree/main/next13), here's how to make it works (at least tested on Next 13.2.4 and FullCalendar 6.1.6):

1. Make sure you installed `@fullcalendar/core` along with other FullCalendar package as you wished.
2. Since we no longer need `next-transpile-modules`, (if you added it before) we can remove it from `next.config.js`. Check example [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/blob/main/next13/next.config.js).
3. Remove all FullCalendar CSS (usually in _app.jsx / _app.tsx).
4. Use FullCalendar component as usual. Check example [here](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-examples/blob/main/next13/pages/index.js).